# Whey does only the 'a' key make a vibrating buzzing sound when pressed on my laptops keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, chromebook

So just recently the letter 'a' on my laptop started making a buzzing vibrating sound when pressed. It sounds like its a wiring problem almost...I can just place my finger on it and feel the vibration. Maybe it has something to with the fan? But why is it only effecting one key..?

Answer (score 1):

I am not too familar with the makeup of the inside of a Chromebook as I don't have one to hand - but there are a couple of possibilities:

- Part of the hard drive directly under the A key
- Part of the fan directly under the A key

It is very very unlikely to be a wiring problem - the keys actually press down onto a curcit board - which is in turn wired to the motherboard by a loom/ribbon cable/slot connector - these wouldn't cause the vibration you are describing.